# Running subtraction in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a number which is the number of sessions of therapy a person needs to have in a month.  I want to subtract each session from that number and see the new total every day. How can I get that in Excel?

```
Name  sessions needed   received session on date  received session on date  received session on date
Joe       8                    1                             1                    1
```

I want the 8 to change each time a session is added.

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the worksheet, it would make alot of sense showing what you want to do.

Comment: Can you use a macro? And what's wrong with `=8-SUM(B1:Z1)` or something?

Answer (score 2):

It would make more sense to have two fields instead of just `Sessions Needed`. You need something like `Sessions` and `Sessions Remaining`.

`Sessions` would be a fixed number, the total number of sessions the person must do.

`Sessions Remaining` would be a formula that subtracts the listed received sessions from the value in `Sessions`.

If `Sessions` is in column B and `Sessions Remaining` is in column C, the formula you need would be something like:

```
=B2-SUM(INDIRECT("D"&ROW()&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),B2+COLUMN(),4)))
```

The business inside the `SUM` function is just a fancy way of looking only at as many columns as the number of sessions (in `B2`) for that person.